# Multi maven web modules packaged in EAR depolyed on WAS 8.5 give me JAXBException this class not known to this context

Tags: maven, soap, jaxb, websphere, ear

There are multi maven modules jars and wars and I package these modules into EAR using maven and deploy it on WebSphere 8.5, the problem happened within specific web module has soap service when I send request give me this exception:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: com.fawryis.ebpp.fawryswitch.businessfacade.ProcessRequest is not known to this context

My web module jaxb object:

```
package com.fawryis.ebpp.fawryswitch.businessfacade;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import com.fawry_eg.ebpp.ifxmessages.FAWRYType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "processRequest", namespace = "http://businessfacade.fawryswitch.ebpp.fawryis.com/", propOrder = {"arg0"})
public class ProcessRequest {

  protected FAWRYType arg0;

  /**
   * Gets the value of the arg0 property.
   * 
   * @return possible object is {@link FAWRYType }
   * 
   */
  public FAWRYType getArg0() {

    return arg0;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the arg0 property.
   * 
   * @param value allowed object is {@link FAWRYType }
   * 
   */
  public void setArg0(FAWRYType value) {

    this.arg0 = value;
  }

}
```

My web module pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.fawryis</groupId>
        <artifactId>Wallet</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>PaymentWebService</artifactId>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>PaymentWebService</name>
    <description>Source of Fund PaymentWebService.</description>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fawryis</groupId>
            <artifactId>FawryIFXMessagesModulesDataModel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fawryis</groupId>
            <artifactId>GeneralDataModel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fawryis</groupId>
            <artifactId>PosSofejbClient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fawryis</groupId>
            <artifactId>PosSofExceptions</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fawryis</groupId>
            <artifactId>Logger</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fawryis</groupId>
            <artifactId>CommonConstants</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fawryis</groupId>
            <artifactId>PosSofConstants</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>WebContent\WEB-INF</directory>
<!--                <directory>src/main/resources</directory> -->
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>PaymentWebService</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bus="http://businessfacade.fawryswitch.ebpp.fawryis.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bus:processRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <Request>
               <SignonRq>
                  <ClientDt>2011-06-08T12:00:00</ClientDt>
                  <CustLangPref>en-gb</CustLangPref>
                  <SuppressEcho>false</SuppressEcho>
                  <SignonProfile>
                     <Sender>FAWRY</Sender>
                     <Receiver>60</Receiver>
                     <MsgCode>InvalidateCacheRq</MsgCode>
                     <Version>V1.0</Version>
                  </SignonProfile>
               </SignonRq>
               <UtilSvcRq>
                  <RqUID>f37bec7e-7090-c244-4321-824d115d8001</RqUID>
                  <AsyncRqUID>11112222-3333-4444-5555-111122332300</AsyncRqUID>
                  <MsgRqHdr>
                     <NetworkTrnInfo>
                        <OriginatorCode>TANMYAH</OriginatorCode>
                        <TerminalId>33933</TerminalId>
                     </NetworkTrnInfo>
                     <ClientTerminalSeqId>1</ClientTerminalSeqId>
                     <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty>
                           <Key>PosSerialNumber</Key>
                           <Value>456457457</Value>
                        </CustomProperty>
                     </CustomProperties>
                  </MsgRqHdr>
                  <InvalidateCacheRq/>
               </UtilSvcRq>
            </Request>
         </arg0>
      </bus:processRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hey! Seems like a few things could be going on here, as there could be multiple reasons why the JAX-B object isn't being associated with the JAXBContext. The first question that comes to mind is if there is an ObjectFactory class associated with the package that this JAX-B Object is declared in. Looks like `com.fawryis.ebpp.fawryswitch.bussinessfacade` , so is there a `com.fawryis.ebpp.fawryswitch.bussinessfacade.ObjectFactory` class with the appropriate getters and setters for the `ProcessReqest` object?

Comment: First. Thanks for your reply ...
Second: Yes there are object factory in the same package but without getter and setter for the ProcessReqest object , is this the problem?